# Display only products from the logged in author on WooCommerce admin products list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

Is there a way, by which this Admin product dashboard shows only the products created by the logged-in user?

I am trying `manage_{$post->post_type}_posts_custom_column` function but cannot move much

E.g. I want something like this

```
add_action( 'manage_product_posts_custom_column', 'custom_column_content', 10, 2 );
function custom_column_content( $column, $product_id ){
        if( logged in user==Product Author){
            Display product;
        }
        else{
            Dont display product
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `manage_product_posts_custom_column` hook is made to manipulate the columns content from admin products list.

So you need instead to alter the **product query** from admin products list using:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'admin_pre_get_posts_product_query' );
function admin_pre_get_posts_product_query( $query ) {
    global $pagenow;

    // Targeting admin product list
    if( is_admin() && 'edit.php' == $pagenow && isset($_GET['post_type']) && 'product' === $_GET['post_type'] ) {
        $query->set( 'author', get_current_user_id() ); // Only displays the products created by the current user
    }
}
```

Code goes in *functions.php* file of your active child theme *(or active theme)*. Tested and works.

> Now you will have only the products belonging to the current user ID, as we filter products by logged in author.

---

**Allowing a specific user role to view all products:**

If you want to allow only "administrator" user role to view all products, you will insert in the code, just after `global $pagenow;` the following lines:

```
    // Allow administrator user roles
    if( current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) return;
```

Comment: I am still able to see the products (view only) . This link shows all the products `edit.php?post_type=product&all_posts=1` but this link `edit.php?post_type=product` shows only authors product(as expected). I am logged in as 'Shop Manager'

Comment: @Learner For me the code works perfectly as expected with both links: `&all_posts=1` has no effect and doesn't change the query restriction.

Comment: The All button on the top (just above the list table) allows me to view all the products.

Comment: Got it. @LoicTheAztec. I blindly copy pasted the code. The function name in add action and actual function name doesnt matches in the answer. Can you please edit the answer.

Comment: @Learner Oh yes sorry I forgot that when renaming the function… sorry :)